# System.ArgumentException on restoring ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Font

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have simple c# outlook plugin which saves current font on one button click event and restores it back on second event.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var a = Globals.ThisAddIn;
        Outlook.Inspector inspector = a.Application.ActiveInspector();
        if (inspector.EditorType == OlEditorType.olEditorWord)
        {
            Word.Document doc = inspector.WordEditor;
            Word.Application app = doc.Application;
            FontArr.Push(app.Selection.Font);
        }
    }

    private void PopFormat_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var a = Globals.ThisAddIn;
        Outlook.Inspector inspector = a.Application.ActiveInspector();
        if (inspector.EditorType == OlEditorType.olEditorWord)
        {
            Word.Document doc = inspector.WordEditor;
            Word.Application app = doc.Application;
            Word.Font f = FontArr.Pop();
            app.Selection.Font = f; // at this line exception occurs.
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Duplicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822380(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Font class which returns a read-only Font object that represents the character formatting of the specified font. You can use the **Duplicate** property to pick up the settings of all the properties of a duplicated Font object. You can assign the object returned by the Duplicate property to another Font object to apply those settings all at once. Before assigning the duplicate object to another object, you can change any of the properties of the duplicate object without affecting the original.

```
 FontArr.Push(app.Selection.Font.Duplicate);
```

Comment: I modified code like:
    FontArr.Push(app.Selection.Font.Duplicate);
Didn't work :(.